# How to find the sum of elements of a specific tuple in a list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

More specifically, how would I use a loop to get the sum of each tuple (n) and add that as a key to a new dict with the value as the specific tuple which I got the sum from.

What I tried:

`dict = list(map(sum, list_with_tuples))`

So for example I want to take this as input:

`list = [(50, 55), (56, 57), (58, 62)]`

And have this as output:

`dict = 105: [50, 55], 113: [56, 57], 120: [58, 62]`

Comment: Please provide your code, along with error and your expected result

See [How do I ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `dict` is a reserved keyword, don't use it. And please provide a [minimum reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
l = [(50, 55), (56, 57), (58, 62)]
d = {}
for x in l:
  d[sum(x)] = x
```

If several lists have the same sum value, it will get overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
myDict = {}
# HERE DEFINE THE LISTS
myListX = [LIST OF THE NAME OF LISTS]
for x in myListX:
  myDict[x] = sum(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reduce each list to a sum, you should you use `reduce` If you have a list of lists n

```py
from functools import reduce

list_dict = {}

for list in in n:
     list_dict[reduce(lambda a+b, list)] = list
```

Comment: You shouldn't use list, as it is a reserved keyword. Also, using reduce(lambda a+b, list) is quite overkill given that you have an operation such as sum which is already well suited for this. (if the lists are quite big it will probably increase the cost quite a bit too)